# Listener inside IIFE/function (not in global scope) in ManifestV3 service worker?

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, scope, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Manifest v3 service workers require listeners are defined in the global scope of a file, webpack compiles to inside an anonymous function.  These two things seems basically incompatible.  Does anyone have a solution better than ditching webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Manifest v3 service workers require listeners are defined in the global scope of a file

There's no such requirement, it's an incorrect/inaccurate claim in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/): *"top level of your script"* is a misrepresentation of the technical terms used to describe the JS engine internals.

The *actual requirement* is to **register the listeners in the main (synchronous) phase of the first task of the JS event loop**, which may certainly happen inside a function:

```js
(() => {
  (() => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => { /* ..... */ });
  })();
})();
```

Comment: Oh okay I see, thank you, also I have seen you across Manifest v3 chats, so thank you for contributing to public knowledge!